# Why does addition of ReactJS module to an existing site breaks all JavaScript events?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I have written a ReactJS module to start replacing parts of my older site incrementally.  The module functions as expected, but an existing Rails app breaks as follows:

1. Bootstrap drop-down menus are no longer working.
2. Any script registered in CoffeeScript file as `$ ->` (or `(function() {} )(this));` for JS equivalent) no longer works.

I have tried ordering the ReactJS bundle files built with webpack before or after the remaining scripts with no luck.  I am now inclined to think that React module somehow interferes with the legacy scripts.

Does anyone know if there is a way to overcome the issue?

There are no errors showing in JS Console of the browser.

Comment: Where in the dom is react bound? If it's on one or more independent nodes, you shouldn't have a problem. But that node (and all it's children) needs to be more or less 100% react.

Comment: I am binding the react module inside a "container" seated within the "body" node.  It rests within the site layout, which includes a nested Bootstrap styled menu.

Comment: add your webpack config and index.html

Comment: Thanks @goldylucks - the configs are nested and a little too complex for me to extract the relevant part.  Do you think it should have something to do with webpack then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.  It appears that Bootstrap.js file was referenced in 2 places (in rails application.js file and, what eluded me at the time, in webpack configuration file as dependency that was compiled.)

Additionally, the jQuery events seem to have been broken due to Turbolinks caching (that I did not realize were enabled.)

Such a combination appears to cause silent issues.

Comment: I think u r not setting your project correctly. I suggest u use the rails app as an API only, and let webpack manage the client build. U r going to run into a lot more problems like these as your app grows